# No Role exists with the key {companyId=1, name=Owner} error in liferay portlet

Tags: liferay

I'm using Service Builder in my portlet. Here is my addProduct method in `PRProductLocalServiceBaseImpl`:

```java
public class PRProductLocalServiceImpl extends PRProductLocalServiceBaseImpl {
    public PRProduct addProduct(long companyID, long groupID, String productName,    String serialNumber, long userID) throws SystemException, PortalException{
        PRProduct product = prProductPersistence.create(counterLocalService.increment(PRProduct.class.getName()));
        resourceLocalService.addResources(companyID, groupID, userID, PRProduct.class.getName(), product.getPrimaryKey(), false, true, true);
        product.setProductName(productName);
        product.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
        product.setCompanyId(companyID);
        product.setGroupId(groupID);        

        return prProductPersistence.update(product, false);
    }
}
```

When I call this method from my portlet class and pass 1 as companyID it gives "No Role exists with the key {companyId=1, name=Owner}". and here is my portlet class:

```java
public void addProduct(ActionRequest actionReaquest, ActionResponse actionResponse) 
{   
    PortletSession session = actionReaquest.getPortletSession();
    try
    {
        String productName = actionReaquest.getParameter("productName");
        String userID = actionReaquest.getParameter("userID");
        String companyID = actionReaquest.getParameter("companyID");
        String groupID = actionReaquest.getParameter("groupID");
        String serialNumber = actionReaquest.getParameter("serialNumber");
        PRProduct product = PRProductLocalServiceUtil.addProduct(Long.parseLong(companyID), Long.parseLong(groupID), productName, 
                serialNumber, Long.parseLong(userID));          
        session.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Product added successfully");                         
        actionResponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/ProductAdded.jsp");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        session.setAttribute("errorMessage", e.getMessage());           
        actionResponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/ProductAdded.jsp");
    }

}
```

Can any body help? Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have checked to see if the Company ID is in fact 1?

The best way to get the current Liferay User ID, Group ID, and Company ID is by the `ThemeDisplay`object. So instead of using your code:

```java
String userID = actionReaquest.getParameter("userID");
String companyID = actionReaquest.getParameter("companyID");
String groupID = actionReaquest.getParameter("groupID");
```

**You should use:**

```java
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionReaquest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
long realUserId = themeDisplay.getRealUserId();
long companyId = themeDisplay.getCompanyId();
long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
```

This way you'll get the values from Liferay, rather than having to pass them in yourself. It also means you don't have to a `Long.parseLong()` to get the Long value of a String.

See if this helps! It's also better practice to do it this way for any future portlets. The ThemeDisplay objects holds a lot of useful information!

Also minor thing, it's spelt "request" not "reaquest" :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add the content as an admin user or Owner user, below is the example to ass the content as the admin user set the adminUser permission before adding the content, try same for Owner:

```java
User adminUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(companyId,"test@liferay.com");
permissionChecker = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.create(adminUser);
PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(permissionChecker);
```

or just fetch the owner the using code below:

```java
Role role=com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(long companyId,"Owner");
```

and update the add method add one more argument in add method i.e. `serviceContext` and all role(owner) in it,as we do while adding User in liferay.